# Parsing field from large JSON file where another field meets a condition, using Python

Tags: python, json, azure

I've never worked with JSON files before and I cannot find a way to get certain fields out of the file using Python. The file in question is the Azure Service Tags file which lists all the Azure services by region and lists out the IP addresses used. The latest file can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519 but a sample is below (it's over 70,000 lines).

```
{
  "changeNumber": 135,
  "cloud": "Public",
  "values": [
    {
      "name": "ActionGroup",
      "id": "ActionGroup",
      "properties": {
        "changeNumber": 7,
        "region": "",
        "regionId": 0,
        "platform": "Azure",
        "systemService": "ActionGroup",
        "addressPrefixes": [
          "13.66.60.119/32",
          "13.66.143.220/30",
          "13.66.202.14/32",
          "13.66.248.225/32",
          "13.66.249.211/32",
          "13.67.10.124/30",
          "13.69.109.132/30"
        ],
        "networkFeatures": [
          "API",
          "NSG",
          "UDR",
          "FW"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ApplicationInsightsAvailability",
      "id": "ApplicationInsightsAvailability",
      "properties": {
        "changeNumber": 2,
        "region": "",
        "regionId": 0,
        "platform": "Azure1",
        "systemService": "ApplicationInsightsAvailability",
        "addressPrefixes": [
          "13.86.97.224/27",
          "13.86.98.0/27",
          "13.86.98.48/28",
          "13.86.98.64/28",
          "20.37.156.64/27",
          "20.37.192.80/29"
        ],
        "networkFeatures": [
          "API",
          "NSG",
          "UDR",
          "FW"
        ]
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is "if the regionId is between 27 and 30, print the addressPrefixes". I've tried doing this with jsonpath_rw, jsonpath_rw_ext, pandas, and probably some other ways (I've been looking at this sporadically for a while).

This code will print a list of unique region ID's (using jsonpath_rw_ext):

```
with open(r'C:\Temp\ServiceTags_Public_20210215.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

listRegionId = []
for regionId in jp.match("$..properties.regionId", data):
    if regionId not in listRegionId:
        listRegionId.append(regionId)
print(listRegionId)
```

If I change the if statement to `if regionId == 30:` how can I then reference the addressPrefixes field?

Many thanks

Edit to add I'm a network engineer who can do a bit of Python so my code isn't the best

Comment: im assuming this is one complete data? next would be : "changeNumber": 135,
  "cloud": "Public",
  "values": []?

Comment: @Neeraj, I believe that is correct. My understanding is the list is updated each week (Mondays I think) and each list is a complete list rather than a delta from the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```
import json
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for element in data['values']:
    region_id = element['properties']['regionId']
    if 27 < region_id < 30:
        print('RegionId: ' + str(region_id))
        print(element['properties']['addressPrefixes'])
```

I tried it on the json data you attached, can't display entire output so here's a sample of it:

```
RegionId: 29
['2603:1020:305:402::178/125']
RegionId: 28
['2603:1020:605:402::178/125']
RegionId: 29
['13.87.122.84/31', '13.87.123.144/28', '2603:1020:305:402::140/124']
RegionId: 28
['51.137.136.0/32', '51.140.210.84/31', '51.140.211.176/28', '2603:1020:605:402::140/124']
RegionId: 29
['2603:1020:305:402::a0/123']
```

Comment: Great - thanks, this works nicely. I can see where I was going wrong now

Comment: @AndrewC glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access a sort of deeper level in python dictionaries by using double squared brackets.

This should do the trick:

```
with open('ServiceTags_Public_20210405.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for entry in data["values"]:
    if 27 < entry['properties']["regionId"] < 30:
        print(entry['properties']["addressPrefixes"])
```